# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error by applying ajax on a node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am running a script on front end with ajax (by "get" method with route in "/get?time=")trying to get data from back end in nodejs code. But the program stop at "res.send()". Then got no response on front. Could anybody provide any ideas to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Front End

```
        var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAUUcpvcottIkYXfpwAZfT4axxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "test-9caab.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://test-9xxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "test-9xxxx",
        storageBucket: "test-9xxxxappspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "1280039xxxxxx"
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        function get(){                                     
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();                 
            req.open("get","/get?time="+time);                                                                      
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            req.onload = function(){                        
                var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);    
                show(data);                                 
            };
            req.send();                                     
        }

        function show(data){                                
            var list = document.getElementById("list");     
            list.innerHTML="";  
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){               
                list.innerHTML=data[i].time.bold()+"<br/>"+data[i].temp+"<br/>"+data[i].humid+""+"<hr/>"+list.innerHTML;
                time =data[i].time+1;                   
            }
        }
        var time=0;  
        window.onload = function(){                     
            get();
            window.setInterval(get, 10000);                 
        }
```

Back End

```
app.use(express.static("public"));

  app.get("/get", function (req, res) {
    var time = req.query.time;
    info.orderByChild("time").startAt(time).once("value",function(snapshot){
        var total = snapshot.numChildren();     
        var messages =[];
        snapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot){
            messages.push(itemSnapshot.val());      
            if(messages.length >=total){
                res.json(messages);
            }
        })
    });
  });
```

and run on Chrome with localhost:5438/N01_index.html when server is up and running.

then I got error message on the console

```
N01_index.html:45 GET http://localhost:5438/get?time=0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE              get?time=0
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code executed `res.json`, this error means that your server  haven't response anything, no only `body` but `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script send nothing in case of messages.lengthif condition from `forEach` and put `res.json(message)` outside the forEach. In this case if message is empty frontend receive empty array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. I realize the front end dose not acquire any data from back end. I modify the front end on 2nd and 3rd lines below. and the issue is solved.

```
app.get("/get", function (req, res) {
    var time = parseInt(req.query.time);
    var info = firebase.database().ref('/info');

    info.orderByChild("time").startAt(time).once("value",function(snapshot){
        var total = snapshot.numChildren();         
        console.log("total= ",total);
        var messages =[];
        snapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot){
            messages.push(itemSnapshot.val());      
            console.log(messages);
            if(messages.length >=total){
                res.json(messages);
            }
        })
    });
});
```